# Passing data to another component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my code, I have it so the user can search for the type of Pokémon they want. When the user submits it, I want to send it to another component to display all the information. The issue is that the data isn’t passing through to the other component. I’m pretty new to react, so I might be missing something obvious.

This is the component that retrieves the data from the API.

```
const Search = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);
  const userInput = (e) => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    apiCall(inputValue);
  };

  const apiCall = async (name) => {
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${name}`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    setUserData(data);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button className="btn" onClick={handleClick}>
        Search
      </button>
      <input
        type="search"
        onChange={userInput}
        value={inputValue}
        placeholder="Enter your pokemon name"
        className="btn-search"
      ></input>
      <div>
        <PokiApi props={userData} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is the component that I want to display the API data to the page.

```
export default class PokiApi extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: props.props,
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>{this.state.data}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[When I run it this is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFE0K.png)

Comment: Try passing the props with some other name than **props** in `<PokiApi props={userData} />`, because there might be a problem with react keywords name.

Comment: You may want to stick either with function components or class components.

Comment: Is there any reason that `PokeApi` class component needs its own state? Why not just render the data you pass in as props. (You can test this by removing that constructor and using `this.props.props.height` in that div, or change it to a function component to make life a little easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`This` is what you need

```
const Search = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState();

  const userInput = (e) => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const apiCall = async (name) => {
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${name}`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    setUserData(data);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    apiCall(inputValue);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form action='' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <button className='btn'>Search</button>
        <input type='search' onChange={userInput} value={inputValue} placeholder='Enter your pokemon name' className='btn-search' />
      </form>
      <div>
        <PokiApi data={userData} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
const PokiApi = ({ data }) => {
  // data is an array
  if (!data) {
    return <div>Enter pokemon to get the data</div>;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data.name}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const PokiApi({props}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>{props}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

the props in the function component will be userData and props.props is undefined

Comment: this will display [object:object] since props is an object.